# Different definitions of cographs

Tags: graph-theory

The inductive definition of cographs states, that:

1. $K_1$ is a cograph
2. if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are cographs, then $G_1 \cup G_2$ is a cograph
3. if $G$ is a cograph, then $\overline{G}$ is a cograph

Another definition states that:
$$G \text{ is cograph } \iff G \text{ or } \overline{G} \text{ is not connected}$$

The question is, how these two definitions are equivalent, especially how the second definiton implies the first one.

Answer (score 2):

These are not equivalent. For example, take the disjoint union of two copies of $P_4$ (the path on $4$ vertices). This satisfies the second definition, since it's not connected.

However, it does not satisfy the first definition - the only way to build $2P_4$ out of smaller cographs would be if $P_4$ were a cograph, and $P_4$ does not satisfy *either* definition.

The first definition is the standard definition of a cograph. As far as I know, the second definition does not describe an interesting class of graphs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't think this example works.
If the graph is the disjoint union of two copies of P_4, then its complement is connected and therefore the second definition is also not satisfied.

Comment: @amelie The second condition says that either $G$ *or* its complement is not connected, which is true here: $2P_4$ itself is not connected. There are no graphs such that both $G$ and $\overline{G}$ are disconnected.